# How can I run jquery dropdown open/close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

My project is a dropdown with choice (here nation) not link,it must be like a select with some option

I have a problem with my dropdown when I have only one dropdown all is ok,
but I have 4 in my project and I look some reactions when Open/close the dropdown or when I make a choice in my dropdown.
Not close or just one close and other dropdown stay open
li stay but not content

my code is here for more details

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $container = $('.dropdown-menu'),
    $list = $('.dropdown-menu ul'),
    listItem = $list.find('li');

$(".dropdown .title").click(function () {
    if($container.height() > 0) {
        closeMenu(this);
    } else {
        openMenu(this);
    }
});

$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function () {
    closeMenu(this);
});

function closeMenu(el) {
    $(el).closest('.dropdown').toggleClass("closed").find(".title").text($(el).text());
  $(el).next().css("height", 0);
    $list.css( "top", 0 );
}

function openMenu(el) {console.log(el);
    $(el).parent().toggleClass("closed");

    $(el).next().css({
        height: 200
    })
        .mousemove(function(e) {
        var heightDiff = $list.height() / $container.height(),
            offset = $container.offset(),
            relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top),
            top = relativeY*heightDiff > $list.height()-$container.height() ?
            $list.height()-$container.height() : relativeY*heightDiff;

      //  $list.css("top", -top);
    });
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yuki95/0wo01j8y/

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the inconsistent behavior is caused by this line

```
if($container.height() > 0) {
```

Try checking for the `closed` class instead

```
if($(this).closest('.dropdown').hasClass("closed")) {
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c74zwfo0/)

**Update**

In order to close other dropdowns change this

```
$(el).next().css("height", 0);
```

to this

```
$(el).closest('.dropdown').find('.title').next().css("height", 0);
```

and add code to your `openMenu` function that calls `closeMenu` for all other closed menus

```
$('.dropdown:not(.closed) .title').not(el).each(function(){
    closeMenu(this);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e81Lemmg/

Comment: I tried this but when you choice a country ul stay open. 
I need ul close when you choice a country.
height : 0 but ul stay open I don't know why

Comment: all is ok now thanks! 
even if my project manager change project and now he want select 2 choice, here 2 nation and in the order. which finish 1st and 2nd.
( I hate project manager 50 project with a short deadline i'm junior lol )

Answer (score 0):

I would make it simpler

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/0wo01j8y/1/>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: thanks but with your code I can't make choice 
in my dropdown must be like a select with some options

Answer (score 0):

I would do like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style>
    #nav li ul {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div id="nav">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Subject</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Subject</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Subject</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Subject</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Subject</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Subject</a></li>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav li a').click(function() {

        $('#nav li ul').hide();

        $(this).next('ul').fadeIn();

    });

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```